# PHP ZipArchive::addGlobe() is slow I can not delete temp directory

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I have a code which

1. Generate csv files to temp directory
2. Call `ZipArchive::addGlob()`
3. Then remove temp dir

But it seems the `addGlobe()` is not enough fast and files are deleted before `addGlob()` creates the zip file.

Code looks like:

```
function saveCsvDaysDataZip($campaign_id)
{
    $tempDirName = CampaignsDeviceDays::CSV_REPORTS_DIR . '/' . $campaign_id . '/temp';

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zip->open($tempDirName . 'reports.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

    $addGlob = $zip->addGlob("$tempDirName/*", GLOB_BRACE, ['remove_all_path' => TRUE]);
    if( $addGlob === false ) throw  new \Exception("CampaignsDeviceDays::saveCsvDaysDataZip() error: \$zip->addGlobe() failed. " . $this->zipArchive->getStatusString() );
}


public function removeCsvExportsDir($campaign_id)
{
    $dirName = self::CSV_REPORTS_DIR . '/' . $campaign_id . '/temp';
    FileSystem::delete($dirName);
}

$saveCsvDaysDataZip($campaign_id);
$removeCsvExportsDir($campaign_id);
```

Is it possible that `removeCsvExportsDir($campaign_id)` is called before `addGlob()` is done?

Comment: You talk about _"it seems .... files are deleted"_, there must be a reason for that. What are **the exact symptoms**? Do you get an error message? An incomplete/corrupt ZIP file? Can you describe exactly what happens? Please add this to your question.

Comment: Why is there no call to `ZipArchive::close` at the end of your `saveCsvDaysDataZip`?

Comment: @CBroe Thats the reason. Need to call close(). Make an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function had no call to `ZipArchive::close` - which I guess PHP will then take as "permission" to continue populating the ZIP archive in the background, and return before that process is actually finished.

Comment: I though close is not necessary and php will close it at the end of the script once. But it seems it is necessary.